# Single Letter/ Alphabet recognition in AR

Tags: unity, vuforia

I am developing an AR game with unity where I need to recognize alphabets in runtime. I have tried vuforia but it does not support single letter recognition. OpenCV is an alternative solution, but I don't understand how to detect text in Runtime with OpenCV.

I have also tried object recognition, NFT and markerless tracking. But all of these failed because a single letter does not have enough feature to get detected.

I am really new in Augmented reality and image processing. Can anyone give me a guideline or plan what I should do?
I am using this letter blocks from amazon https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B0006MU23W/ref=s9u_simh_gw_i1?ie=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B0006MU23W&pd_rd_r=22ef1e20-b08e-11e7-91cc-bbe5f37c0d0f&pd_rd_w=wCg3M&pd_rd_wg=NG8Lg&pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=TH85A9MZFVDZPD8YYR5P&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=09a46553-65cf-45b2-8aaa-e9bb559981ab&pf_rd_i=desktop

Comment: Vuforia is going to never work with these. Vuforia wants 400 hard-edged high-contrast corners it can pick up on to do the requisite distance/rotation/scale calculations in order to detect targets.

Comment: Any idea how can I approach?

Comment: Sadly, no, I do not have any ideas.